# How to search .token files in a folder and replace "__" in front and end of character via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, token, octopus-deploy

I would like to search thru files with .token files that have a string with the following pattern `__[characters]__` and perform the following via PowerShell:

- remove "__" (two underscores) in front of any character with an "#{"
- remove "__" (two underscores) at the end of the same character and replace with "}"

For example:

```
__STAGE__
to
#{STAGE}
```

I am migrating RM token files to Octopus Deploy and need a clean up step via scripting.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most basic way and assuming there's no problem fitting a token file into memory:

```
$TokenFiles = Get-ChildItem *.token

foreach ($file in $TokenFiles) {
    $NewContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
    $NewContent = $NewContent -replace '__(.*?)__', '#{$1}'
    Set-Content $file.FullName -Value $NewContent
}
```

Comment: What if you add variable for path and folder? Example: $folder = "Y:\CMGitWorkspace\"
$product = "GAM"

Comment: and perform search on "$folder\$product"

Comment: @Chaka Try it.  I'm not writing your complete script for you, I'm giving you a suggestion to answer your specific issue.  "How do I use `Get-ChildItem`?" is a very different (and extremely basic) question compared "How do I search and replace text in a file?"